# Filter a list of strings to create a separate list of those that match a given prefix

Tags: list, string, mapping, filtering

If I have a list, `(“apple” “pear” “grape” “apricot”)` how do I create a new list with elements starting with the letter “a”? The new list will be: `(“apple” “apricot”)`.

Comment: Are the words present together in the buffer, or are they scattered among other text? What do you mean by "copy" - copy all of the words together, to the kill-ring/clipboard, so you can paste them all together? The question really isn't clear (unless maybe someone knows just what that `awk` expression does).

Comment: @Drew I added a sample list for the awk code. I was thinking a function that takes these words and returns only a list with words starting with the letter k.

Comment: @Drew The words may be in alist, instead of the buffer.

Comment: Are you asking how to delete all lines that don't begin with the letter `k`? Or are you asking how to create a new buffer with copies of the lines that begin with the letter `k`? Or something else? Try to specify just what you're looking for.

Comment: This may help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by "*This awk code `$ awk /^k/ file` copies all words starting with the letter “k” in a list in file.*"? I tested it and got nothing.

Comment: @Drew Sorry, the question was not clear. I changed it. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @shynur Sorry about that. I changed the question. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: The question is clear now, and it's a far cry from what it was originally, which talked about "words", "buffer", in a jumbled, incomplete way. Thx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```lisp
(seq-filter (apply-partially #'string-prefix-p "a")
            '("apple" "pear" "grape" "apricot"))
```

If you have other similar questions, consult the `seq` library, which provides some functions to manipulate *sequence* (including *list*).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was trying to do. Functions listed here https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html is the `seq` librarary, right?

Comment: @zeynel Just type `C-h f seq- <tab>` in Emacs

Comment: This is the answer, IMO. Corresponds exactly to the question posed: nothing missing or hidden.

Answer (score 4):

For this specific use-case, you can also reuse a builtin function related to [text completion](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Completion.html) named [`all-completions`](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Completion.html#index-all_002dcompletions):

```el
(all-completions "a" '("apple" "pear" "grape" "apricot"))
;; => ("apple" "apricot")
```

For more details, see `C-h f all-completions RET`.

Comment: This is so simple. I accepted this one. Is @shynur's answer more general?

Comment: I think the accepted answer should mention `completion-regexp-list`, since it's not necessarily true that `all-completions` uses basic (i.e., plain prefix) completion. See [Basic Completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Completion.html).

Comment: IOW, this answer really hides what's needed and how it *might* be solved by `all-completions`: filtering according to a prefix string.

Comment: @zeynel Yes, @shynur's answer is more general since `seq-filter` accepts arbitrary predicates as its first argument. Furthermore, it works on any type that satisfies the predicate `seqp`, whereas `all-completions` works on specific collection types (each with slightly different semantics) and is not extensible.

Comment: @Drew I didn't see the point in complicating a straightforward answer to a straightforward question, given that (a) the documentation of `all-completions` already mentions `completion-regexp-list`; and (b) the global value of `completion-regexp-list` should normally be `nil`, as per its documentation.

Comment: @Drew So I'm not sure what you mean by `this answer really hides what's needed and how it might be solved by all-completions: filtering according to a prefix string`, since as far as I can tell that's exactly what `all-completions` does in this case.

Comment: @Basil: You're right, I shouldn't have mentioned `completion-regexp-list`, any more than arg `PREDICATE` - those are *additional*, optional tests made after *matching*. And yes, `all-completions` does use only **literal-prefix comparison** to do the matching. I'll leave my mistaken comments, for info. And I've just filed Emacs [bug #66147](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=66147), to have the doc specify that **matching** for functions such as `all-completions` means literal-prefix string matching.